# Attempting to receive and print UDP Multicast in Python never prints

Tags: python, udp, multicast

Running the following code never prints any packets and stays stuck on "waiting to receive message." (I have obscured the IPs, even though they are private IPs.  They are valid.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import binascii
import sys

MCAST_GRP = '224.x.x.x'
MCAST_PORT = 12345 
MCAST_IFACE = '10.x.x.x'

def joinMcast(mcast_addr,port,if_ip):
  """
  Returns a live multicast socket
  mcast_addr is a dotted string format of the multicast group
  port is an integer of the UDP port you want to receive
  if_ip is a dotted string format of the interface you will use
  """

  #create a UDP socket
  mcastsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

  #allow other sockets to bind this port too
  mcastsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

  #explicitly join the multicast group on the interface specified
  mcastsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP,socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
      socket.inet_aton(mcast_addr)+socket.inet_aton(if_ip))

  #finally bind the socket to start getting data into your socket
  mcastsock.bind((mcast_addr,port))

  return mcastsock

def main():
  sock = joinMcast(MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT, MCAST_IFACE)

  while True:
    print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
    print sock.recv(1024)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

After starting the script, Wireshark confirms that packets are coming in (to MCAST_IFACE).

Why won't the script print the packets?

UPDATE (SOLVED):
needed to set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter to 0.

Comment: Do you have a source and reason for this line `socket.inet_aton(mcast_addr)+socket.inet_aton(if_ip)`?

Comment: I need to make sure I receive only on the NIC interface I specify.